# Catch Events in List<object> C#

Tags: c#

Let me explain my problem as simple as possible.
suppose I have a class Product

```
class Product {
   public event EventHandler Product_Changed;
    int _productId ;
    int productID {
        get { return _productId}
        set{
            _productId = value; 
            Product_Changed(this,null);  // Raise an event that the product Changed
           }}
    string productName  {get;set;}

}
```

Then in another class , I need to use a List of products and whenever ProductId of any of the item changed , I need to catch the event defined in the product class

```
Class Order 
{
 List<Product> OrderProduct = new List<Product>();
  OrderProduct.Add (new Product());
 // Then I change the productId like     
  OrderProduct[0].ProductID=10 ; // I want to catch the Product_Changed
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```
class Order 
{
    List<Product> OrderProduct = new List<Product>();
    var newProduct = new Product();
    newProduct.Product_Changed += (sender, e) => {
        // do something - sender contains the current product 
    }
    OrderProduct.Add(newProduct);

    // Then I change the productId like     
    OrderProduct[0].ProductID=10 ; // I want to catch the Product_Changed
}
```

You can read more about events [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx).